# CBPeripheral disconnects after 30 seconds

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I am using CoreBluetooth to write an app that subscribes to one characteristic with one property: 'notify' which will allow a Raspberry Pi 3 to send an integer digit to be displayed on the app. I have created the service with this characteristic using Pybleno, a  Python direct port of Bleno. I'm able to connect to the service and read its characteristic, but only for 30 seconds - after which the didDisconnect method is fired. On my central I use time.sleep() to alter the frequency at which the data is sent. I noticed that no delay causes the peripheral to disconnect after about 10 seconds, whereas 20-30ms delay causes a disconnect after 30 seconds. Any help would be great! Thank you. (I followed a Core Bluetooth tutorial for reading a Heart Rate monitor)

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

let TranslatorServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "16dedcf4-027f-435f-b1e6-22e601276949")
let PredictionCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "16DEDCF4-027F-435F-B1E6-22E601276950")

var raspberryAsPeripheral: CBPeripheral!

class HRMViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var heartRateLabel: UILabel!

  var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    // Make the digits monospaces to avoid shifting when the numbers change
    heartRateLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: heartRateLabel.font!.pointSize, weight: .regular)
  }

  func onDigitReceived(_ digit: Int) {

    var predictedNumber : String

    if (digit == 16) {
      predictedNumber = ""
    }
    else {
      predictedNumber = String(digit)
    }
    heartRateLabel.text = predictedNumber
    print("Predicted digit: \(digit)")
  }
}

extension HRMViewController : CBCentralManagerDelegate {

  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
      print("central.state is .unknown")
    case .resetting:
      print("central.state is .resetting")
    case .unsupported:
      print("central.state is .unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
      print("central.state is .unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
      print("central.state is .poweredOff")
    case .poweredOn:
      print("central.state is .poweredOn")
      centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [TranslatorServiceCBUUID])
    }
  }

  func centralManager(_ central : CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
    raspberryAsPeripheral = peripheral
    raspberryAsPeripheral.delegate = self

    centralManager.stopScan()
    centralManager.connect(raspberryAsPeripheral)

  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("you connected with the raspberry pi")
    raspberryAsPeripheral.discoverServices([TranslatorServiceCBUUID])
  }

}

extension HRMViewController : CBPeripheralDelegate {

  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

    for service in services {
      print(service)
      peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    }
  }

  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

    for characteristic in characteristics {
      print(characteristic)
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
        peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
      }
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
      }
    }

  }

  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                  error: Error?) {
    switch characteristic.uuid {

    case PredictionCharacteristicCBUUID:
      let whichNumber = predictedValue(from: characteristic)
      onDigitReceived(whichNumber)

    default:
      print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
    }
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    print("DISSSCONNNNECCCTEDDDDD")
  }

  private func predictedValue(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
    guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
    let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

    return Int(byteArray[0])

    /*

     let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
     if firstBitValue == 0 {
     // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd byte
     return Int(byteArray[1])
     } else {
     // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
     return (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[2])
     }

     */

  }
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine.  Your problem is probably on your peripheral side.  You should call `connect` in `didDisconnect` in order to recover from the disconnection.  Do you get a value for `error` in `didDisconnect`?

Comment: I tried print (error.debugDescription) and print (error) but they both return nil. Do you have any experience with Pybleno/Bleno?

Comment: Sorry, no experience with Pybleno. Python is notoriously single threaded though, so `sleep` may well cause issues.  I have used MicroPython on a WiPy with BLE and it works well, but that doesn't really help you :)

Comment: @Paulw11 You were correct! `sleep` was the culprit. No more disconnects. Thanks!